# |#1060 - Duplicate column name 'id'

Tags: dddd

This is my mysql statement:

```
SELECT * FROM(SELECT * FROM icci_conf_detail,icci_conf_location  WHERE 
icci_conf_detail.conf_loc=icci_conf_location.location_name AND  
icci_conf_detail.is_country='international' AND icci_conf_detail.is_active='1'   
ORDER BY icci_conf_detail.conf_date  ASC) t GROUP BY 
icci_conf_location.location_name
```

I am getting this error:

> `|#1060 - Duplicate column name 'id'`

Can you help me please?

Comment: Do both tables have an `id` column?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the CREATE TABLE statements for the tables?